# How do I get my serch path to a database inside my project to work when not hardcoded?

Tags: java

I've written an app that uses a database. The database is included in the project an the searchway works if you run it in Netbeans. If I try to run it independently it works with a hardcoded path to the database, but not with the following.

I'm having trouble with the following bit of code:

```
String Map = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String sokVag = Map + ("\\db\\MIBDB.FDB");

System.out.println(sokVag);

mibdb = new InfDB(sokVag);
new InloggningsFonster(mibdb).setVisible(true);
```

as you can see I've printed the searchway for the database and when I hardcode it:

```
mibdb = new InfDB("C:\\Users\\...\\db\\MIBDB.FDB");
```

Full print of searchway reads:

C:\Users\Carolin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MIB\db\MIBDB.FDB

It works, but when I write:

```
mibdb = new InfDB(sokVag);
```

It does not work. And the error message I get is:

> Couldn't open Firebird database, check your path. Make sure to use .FDB in the end

Any ideas way?

Comment: What is this `InfDB` class and what does it do? Please provide a [mre], including your deployment locations of files, how you run your application. Right now your problem doesn't seem to be directly related to Firebird nor to NetBeans, but just with actual location of files and locating them from your application, so I have removed the tags that I think are not relevant.

Comment: I also don't understand how using `"C:\\Users\\...\\db\\MIBDB.FDB"` would resolve to `C:\Users\Carolin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MIB\db\MIBDB.FDB`, so clearly your code is doing something extra.

Comment: Probably unrelated but make `Map` lowercase, only class name should be capitalized and remove the () around the path addendum. A more standard way of composing the path like File.pathSeparator or Paths (java 7) would be nice. For your problem, if the hardcoded string works and the composed one doesn't, there has to be some kind of difference between the two. They're both strings, print them side-by-side and compare. It could be a "file:///" in front or an encoding issue but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for all your answers, for no apperent reason, after not using the computor for a while and not changing anything, it's working.